# How to send destkop notification with DOM information from 2 browser opened tabs?

Tags: javascript, notifications

I am trying to create a browser extension for personal use that should send me desktop notifications with the .innerText of 2 spans from 2 opened browser tabs. The content of the 2 spans may change on page refresh and I do not want to do it manually. I have a button on my popup.html that opens 2 pages and I should receive a notification every hour, let's say.

In order to present you with a simple example, in the code below, the button from the popup opens 2 Wikipedia pages and the aim is to receive a desktop notification with the title of these 2 pages. The issue I'm currently having with my code is that I receive 2 separate notifications, one for each page. The notifications look like "Undefined title1" and "Undefined title2".

What I should do in order to receive one single notification with the title of these 2 pages? Thank you in advance for you help.

popup.html

```
<body>
    <h2>Hello, this is a test extension.</h2>
     <button id="startBtn">Start</button>
     <script src="./popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

popup.js

```
let win1  = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript")

let win2 = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML")

let startBtn = document.querySelector("#startBtn")

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.open(win1)
    window.open(win2)
})
```

contentscript.js

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("html") > -1) {
  var title1 = document.querySelector("#firstHeading > span").innerText
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf("javascript")){
    var title2 = document.querySelector("#firstHeading > span").innerText
}



if ("Notification" in window) {
    if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        notify();
    } else {
        Notification.requestPermission().then(res => {
            if (res === "granted") {
                notify();
            } else {
                console.error("Did not receive permission for notifications");
            }
        })
    }
} else {
    console.error("Browser does not support notifications");
}

function notify() {

    const notification = new Notification('Here are the titles:',{
        body: title1 +title2,
    
        vibration: [300,200,300],
    });

  

    setTimeout(() => notification.close(), 5*1000);

}
```

I have tried reading the documentation about the Notification api but I could not find something that would help me solve the issue.

Comment: Do you specifically need to have these pages to open it tabs? Because if you don't you can use a background script that periodically fetches the contents of these pages, then use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to extract the innerText of those spans, then finally use the [**web extensions** notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications) to send your notifications.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I tried to implement the simplest version for my skills. However, my issue is that I receive 2 notifications instead of 1 nofification with the content from both tabs.

Comment: I see. Well, the issue is that you have a content script that runs each time a page opens, and since you're opening two tabs then you get two separate notifications because the script operates independently on each page. You want to combine the results into one notification, but I am not sure how you'd be able to achieve that with just a content script, usually this is where background scripts come into play.

Comment: Also, your `title1` and `title2` variables are out of scope to the `notify` function (the function has no access to these variables because they are within a scope of their own). At the start of your code, declare those variables and set them to empty strings - `var title1 = ''` and `var title2 = ''`, then **inside** your first `if` statement re-assign them to the `innerText`. `if (window...) { title1 = document....innerText } `.

Comment: Thank you, I have declared the titles outside the function and it eliminated the undefined from the notification. I'll try with a background script and get back with the result.

Comment: I've been trying to implement this with the help of a background script. I manage to fetch the html of the page, but I'm stuck on parsing it. Do I parse the html in the background script? Or should I send it to the content script and parse it there? The DOM Parser does not work in the background script.

Comment: why isn't the DOMParser working in the background script? I read this might be an issue with manifest v3.